# Using tailwindcss with React, size not decreased after purging

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm tried to set up tailwind with ejected create-react-app. I'm successful to make it works but failed to purge the size. here is my setup

**./src/assets/styles/tailwind.css**

```css
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.js"],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js && postcss src/assets/styles/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles/main.css -w",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js && postcss src/assets/styles/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles/main.css"
}
```

**index.js**

```js
import "./assets/styles/main.css";
// ...
```

I tried to create a component like this and its work

```
<div className="w-64 h-64 bg-red-200">hai</div>
```

but when I build, even I have given a path to purge at the config, the size not decreasing. It constant 143kb whether I add the purge path or not. i also have tried manual purge like this at `postcss.config.js` but no work

```js
// postcss.config.js
const purgecss = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss")({
  // Specify the paths to all of the template files in your project
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.js"
    // etc.
  ],

  // This is the function used to extract class names from your templates
  defaultExtractor: (content) => {
    // Capture as liberally as possible, including things like `h-(screen-1.5)`
    const broadMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g) || [];

    // Capture classes within other delimiters like .block(class="w-1/2") in Pug
    const innerMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\s.()]*[^<>"'`\s.():]/g) || [];

    return broadMatches.concat(innerMatches);
  }
});

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [purgecss] : [])
  ]
};
```

whats wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest versions, starting at 1.4.0, you don't need to manually configure PurgeCSS.

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```

```
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
      './src/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

```
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss tailwind.css -o src/main.css"
  },
```

Note the `NODE_ENV=production`.

The [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/controlling-file-size#basic-usage) says:

> Now whenever you compile your CSS with NODE_ENV set to production, Tailwind will automatically purge unused styles from your CSS.

Comment: yes, i didnt put the NODE_ENV production. it works now

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problem. This helped me:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#enabling-manually

I have to manually add this code in my tailwind.config.js file:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: ['./src/**/*.html'],
  },
  // ...
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.